# Std Dev, Mean of every 5 values in data set Python

Tags: python, mean

Calculate mean & std dev of every 5 values in data set? Need to do analysis of football (soccer) final league points of 10 years. Top 5 teams std dev, mean, Hirfendahl Herschman index and CSI5B (England, Germany, Spain, Italy). Please advise. First 20 rows attached below.

[Screenshot from my Data Set - Top 20 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsrrE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from math import sqrt, pow

file_address = "C:/"    # here goes your file address, make sure the backslashes are replaced with normal slashes
data = pd.read_csv(file_address)    # you can replace the "csv" part by the extension of your sheet
total_entries = len(data)

for i in range(total_entries//5):
    sum = 0
    for j in range(5):
        sum += data.iloc[i*5 + j]["Points"]
    mean = sum/5
    
    var_sum = 0
    for j in range(5):
        var_sum += pow(data.iloc[i*5 + j]["Points"], 2)
    variance = var_sum/5
    std_deviation = sqrt(variance)
```

Hope this works!

**Note:** The code will only consider sets of five, as you mentioned. I mean, if there remain less than 5 rows at the end, they are ignored. If necessary you can modify the code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks mate, really appreciate it! Helps a lot, also with understanding since I'm new to programming/python.!

Comment: glad it worked out. If you are wondering about some statement, you can freely ask.